# TNS Error in vb with respect to oracle 10g connection

Tags: oracle, vb6

Im trying to make a vb6 application with oracle 10g as backend but whenever I try to connect via adaoc properties i get this error
http://i59.tinypic.com/msd93a.png

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: You might get more help if you posted your connection string (with any credentials redacted). Also, a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-12154%3A+TNS%3Acould+not+resolve+the+connect+identifier+specified+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) of this error on just stackoverflow.com returned no less than 10 results. Are you sure this hasn't been already answered?

Comment: No im directly connecting through adodc

Comment: I could be mistaken, but unless it works by magic osmosis there must be *some* place where you specify how to connect to the server.